# How i can check what problem in SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have error in plugin wordpress

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'IF' at line 1

**Сall source:**

```
WPB_F_R_WPBRIDGE_UPDATE->WPB_F_R_UpdatePlayersTable()
wp-content/plugins/wpbridge-for-rust/update.php:31
WPB_F_R_WPBRIDGE_UPDATE->__construct()
wp-content/plugins/wpbridge-for-rust/update.php:13
WPB_F_R_WPBRIDGE_UPDATE::WPB_F_R_instance()
wp-content/plugins/wpbridge-for-rust/update.php:81
WPB_F_R_WPBRIDGE->WPB_F_R_CheckVersion()
wp-content/plugins/wpbridge-for-rust/wpbridge.php:104
WPB_F_R_WPBRIDGE->__construct()
wp-content/plugins/wpbridge-for-rust/wpbridge.php:27
WPB_F_R_WPBRIDGE::WPB_F_R_instance()
wp-content/plugins/wpbridge-for-rust/wpbridge.php:161
```

Code from file update.php

```
function WPB_F_R_UpdatePlayersTable()
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".esc_sql(WPBRIDGE_PLAYER_TABLE)."` (
        `id`                        INT(11)         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `steamid`                   BIGINT(100)     NOT NULL,
        `displayname`               VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
        `position`                  VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
        `updated`                   DATETIME        NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) $this->_charset_collate;";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($sql);
}

function WPB_F_R_UpdateLootDataTable()
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".esc_sql(WPBRIDGE_PLAYER_LOOT_TABLE)."` (
        `id`                        INT(11)         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `steamid`                   BIGINT(100)     NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) $this->_charset_collate;";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($sql);
}
```

Comment: The error message does not match shown code, it seems. Enable General Log on MySQL and look what SQL code is received by MySQL in practice.

Comment: I suppose the error is ) $this->_charset_collate;"; because $this must be out from the string. So you must concatenate (as in the first line with the table name)

Comment: Can you dump the generated SQL query and add it to the question, along with your attempts to resolve the problem?